# Degree of this attaching map -- or how to define this attaching map?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the cell complex consisting of two zero cells $e_0^1, e_0^2$ connected by two 1 cells $e_1^1,e_1^2$ with one 2 cell $e_2$ in the middle (Picture: Imagine $S^1$ with one $0$-cell at the north pole and  the other at the south pole. Glue the disk into this circle.).

[image]

Let $f_1: S^1 \to S^1$, $f_2: S^1 \to S^1$ be the maps that attach the two cell to the two $1$-cells. I am trying to calculate the degree of $f_1,f_2$.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping) the degree is described as " the degree of a continuous mapping between two compact oriented manifolds of the same dimension is a number that represents the number of times that the domain manifold wraps around the range manifold under the mapping."

I understand that. If I apply it to the $2$-cell in my example then half of the $2$-cell wraps once around one of the $1$-cells while the other half wraps around the other $1$-cell.

Therefore we should have $\deg(f_1) = \deg(f_2) = {1\over 2}$. The problem is, in the definition the degree is an integer. How do I calculate the degree of this attaching map correctly?

**Edit**

Maybe my problem is that I don't know how to define the attaching map for this example so that it is one attaching map $S^1\to S^1$ rather than two maps. After all, the degree is define for one map $S^n \to S^n$. But I don't see how I can calculate the degree if I define it using one map.

**Edit 2**

With orientation as assumed in the answer by Ted Shifrin:

[image]

**Edit 3**

In this question I am asking about degrees of **attaching maps** $\chi_n$ as in the definition of cellular homology [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology). I am **not** asking about boundary maps.

Comment: How are you attaching the $S^1$ which is the boundary of your 2-cell to your 1-cell?

Comment: I'm attaching it to 2 2-cells: half to each of it. I tried to explain it by a picture in my first sentence. Sorry that it's not so clear.

Comment: So you're attaching one 2-cell to one of your 1-cells, and your second 2-cell to the remaining 1-cell. Or are you attaching each 2-cell to all of your previous 1-skeleton? Your 1-skeleton is also homeomorphic to $S^1$ so why don't we start with that?

Comment: @JackDavies There is only one two cell in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the boundary map. There is just one circle, formed by the union of the two $1$-cells. (The degree is defined from the boundary of each $2$-cell to each circle in the $1$-skeleton.) So the boundary of the $2$-cell is the sum $e_1^1+e_1^2$. Note that you have $C_2 \cong \Bbb Z$, $C_1 \cong \Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$, and $C_0 \cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$. We have 
\begin{align*}
\partial_2\colon C_2\to C_1\,, &\quad \partial_2(e_2) = e_1^1+e_1^2, \\
\partial_1\colon C_1\to C_0\,, &\quad \partial_1(e_1^1) = e_0^2-e_0^1, \partial_1(e_1^2)= e_0^1-e_0^2.
\end{align*}
You can check that this gives the homology $H_2 \cong 0$, $H_1\cong 0$, $H_0\cong\Bbb Z$, as it should.

Comment: Thank you, this resolves ${1\over 2}$ of my problem. Please, can you tell me the degree of your attaching map $\partial_2$?

Comment: Is it $1$ because $\partial_2$ wraps $S^1=\partial D^2$ once around the circle with boundary $e^1_1 + e^2_1$?

Comment: It's $\pm 1$, depending on orientations. With the "usual" orientations, it will be $+1$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not so clear on that. Say we put an orientation on the two edges and depict it by arrows. Do both arrows have to point in the same direction? (either both clockwise or both CCW?)

Comment: They can be oriented any way you want, but the formulas I wrote above assumed that $e_1^1$ was on the left, heading down, $e_1^2$ on the right heading up. So their sum is a circle oriented CCW.

Comment: Thank you. And why is it $\partial_1(e_1^2)= e_0^1-e_0^2$ and not $\partial_1(e_1^2)= e_0^1 + e_0^2$? I tried go through writing down all the maps and then got stuck because the $0$-cells don't have arrows on them and it's not clear to me how to find the signs for them.

Comment: The boundary of an interval $[a,b]$ (with arrow going to the right) is $(+b)+(-a)$. (This is compatible with what happens with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.)

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Shouldn't the attaching map $\partial_2$ be $$ \partial_2(\partial e_2) = e_1^1 + e_1^2$$ rather than $$ \partial_2(e_2) = e_1^1 + e_1^2$$

I'm wondering because the degree is defined for maps $S^n \to S^n$ and $e_2$ is a disk but $\partial e_2 = S^2$.

Comment: But $\partial$ *is* the boundary map.

Comment: I meant to denote the boundary by $\partial$, that is, (and I also made a typo): shouldn't $\partial_2$ be applied to the boundary of $e_2$ instead of $e_2$? (where the boundary of $e_2$ is $S^1$)

Comment: What are the attaching maps? I just realized you're talking about boundary maps but I am asking about the attaching maps in my question. I need to know how to calculate the degrees of the attaching maps.

Comment: No, the equation tells how to attach the boundary of $e_2$ to the $1$-skeleton.

Comment: Exactly! And therefore $\partial_2(\partial e_2) = e_1^1 + e_1^2$ where $\partial e_2$ denotes the boundary of $e_2$!

Comment: I really need to know how to determine the attaching maps, not the boundary maps. Otherwise I'm none the wiser. I just tried to write down the attaching maps for the $1$-cells in my example to calculate the degrees as given by you in your answer and I couldn't do it.